# Windows 8.1 freezes after running a C++ program

Tags: c++, windows

I've been using Ubuntu for programming and I did use Windows 8 too once in a while, it always went well. Now I upgraded to Windows 8.1 and installed Visual Studio 2013 and Qt Creator with MinGW, so I can learn C++ in any OS I'm using.

The problem is that when I run a C++ program, it freezes what I've been using to run it. I've compiled the program with MinGW and VS compiler and I always have this problem. The code is nothing more than a simple Hello World, so I don't know what's going on. I've ran a C# program through the command prompt in Windows 8.1 and everything went fine, but when I try a C++ program, the command prompt freezes and I can't close it even with taskkill /PID  /t /f, it says:

`ERROR: The process with PID <pid> (child process of PID <pid>) could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.`

Sometimes I can get the command to exit, but it still stays in the tasklist. It even frozen Visual Studio once. Most part of the times, I can't close the command prompt, I can't write anything on it and it stays consuming memory and cpu. I've tried to find a solution, but I couldn't find any, I hope I can get some help here.

**Edit**

I'm using `Avast! 2014` and the code is:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()   {
  std::cout << "Hello, world" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: one possibility: antivirus is interfering

Comment: What antivirus do you have? And just to be sure, please show us your code.

Comment: I highly doubt your program is freezing Windows. Perhaps your mean your program is the one freezing?

Comment: I'm using Avast! 2014 and the code is 

`#include <iostream> 

int main() 

{ 

std::cout << "Hello, world" << std::endl; 

return 0; 

}`

@MarcB Yes, I guess I wrote it wrong, my bad.

Comment: The problem was my antivirus indeed. I turned it off the problem didn't happen, such a simple thing. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I can't answer my own question to close it, because this is a new account with almost no reputation, so I will wait 8 hours or until someone answer that is an antivirus problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From the comments to the question:*

- One possibility: the antivirus is interfering.
- The problem was my antivirus indeed. I turned it off and the problem didn't happen.